# Ruby: Reading large JSON files without Memory leak in JSON

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra

I have a big string that needs to be parsed into a JSON file. Using the regular JSON gem, Yajl, Yajl-FFI and Oj to parse the JSON resulted in several hundred MBs of memory being leaked after parsing the JSON files, even after `GC.start` was called multiple times.

What is the best way to parse JSON from a large string whilst making sure that no memory is leaked?

My Code:

```rb
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

require 'json'

# Obtaining the PID to find RAM usage
PID = `ps -ef | grep readFileTest`.split()[1].strip()
puts "PID: ["+ PID + "]"

def readFile(filePath)
  return File.read(filePath)
end

def writeFile(fileContent, filename)
  f = File.new(filename, "w")
  f.write(fileContent)
  f.close
end

def outRAM()
    puts "RAM: [" +`echo $(pmap #{PID} | grep total)`.strip() + "]"
end

puts "Pre read"
outRAM()

a = readFile('/CI_Pipeline/Profiles/JSONValues/JEF_TC3.json')
puts "After read"
outRAM()

b = JSON.parse(a)
puts "after json parse"
outRAM()

myfile = File.open('testfile.txt',"w");
puts "after opening file"
outRAM()

myfile.write(b);
puts "after write"
outRAM()

myfile.close;
puts "after close"
outRAM()


a = nil
b = nil
c = nil


for i in 0..4
    GC.start
    sleep(1)

    puts "After GC clean:"
    outRAM()
end
```

Output:

```
PID: [10516]
Pre read
RAM: [total 45948K]
After read
RAM: [total 73564K]
after json parse
RAM: [total 332196K]
after opening file
RAM: [total 332196K]
after write
RAM: [total 453976K]
after close
RAM: [total 453976K]
After GC clean:
RAM: [total 393144K]
After GC clean:
RAM: [total 393144K]
After GC clean:
RAM: [total 393144K]
After GC clean:
RAM: [total 393144K]
After GC clean:
RAM: [total 393144K]
```

The output is almost identical when using the aforementioned alternatives for JSON parsing. What can be done to reduce memory usage after reading is complete. The only way I have found to remove the memory usage is by killing the entire parent process.

Comment: The various JSON parsers themselves do not "leak" any memory. Instead, you likely still have some variables referencing data you do intend anymore, such as an IO object, a string holding the read file data or something else. Without seeing the entirety pf your JSON handling code and some memory stats for this specific code, there is not we can say about that though.

Comment: Please post some code so we can analyze what you are currently doing.

Comment: I've added a minimum working example of my scenario, as well as the corresponding output. I think that this shows that the JSON parsing is at fault here, as calling GC.start only clears the same amount of ram that was gained after the file read. The JSON parse takes up too much memory and never frees it afterwards.

Comment: This needs more information, e.g. system info, Ruby version and kind etc. You might also try a [lazy enumerator](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-lazy-enumerators-to-work-with-large-files-in-ruby/) and see if that helps, and probably an `ensure` to make sure the file is closed in that write method.